# wheres the bug? navbar jumped left cant figure it out

Tags: html, css, navbar

working on a pretty simple page, with a navbar and a few links. everything was working, appearing correctly, i then made a change to the html and the navbar links moved left whereas before they were centered. im sure i didnt change any of the css and ive scanned over it manytimes over the last day. i wa going to start rom scratch but heard about stackoverflow and thought id try my luck.

heres the page

http://coleio.com/html/poc.html

thanks :)

Comment: Suggestions: Add the html tag to the question.  Fix the typos in your question.  Include some of the relevant html from the page in the question itself.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions asked here (as Anna said) need to be accompained with the needed code that reflects the issue. In the future than, other people with a similar issue might see if the code matches their and look for the appropriate answer, while your link-to-page might go off and useful to no-one.

Comment: hi, thanks for the warm welcome. i had tried to post the html and cs here but the html was read and it displayed a a page?

Comment: @user3361328, highlight the code and then press Ctrl-K or click the "code" button.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.nav {text-align: center;}` to the CSS

Comment: thanks bud. while im here, how would i expand the with of each button? i have added padding to give equal space between each link, i thought that would increase the button size but when i hover its literally the width of the text

Answer (score 0):

Add text-align:center and width:100% to the style for the ul:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i dont know how i deleted that or missed it ha thanks Michelle.

Comment: No problem! on the question below, instead of adding padding to the li give the padding to the 'a' elements instead.

Comment: that worked but it moved the list to the right a small bit. how would i make the buttons all the same size? with the padding its the width of the letters + the padding, where can i specify a set width for each link? i had all my study notarised but had to do a system restore due to a virus, never thought of backing it up. really putting off going over it all again